# Size of nested deques

Tags: c++, nested, size, deque

I want to get the size of a nested deque, like this one:

```
typedef struct{
deque<int>   vec1;
deque<int>   vec2;
deque<int>   vec3;
}struct_deques;

deque<struct_deques> nestedVecs;
```

However, when I want to access the size of the first deque, after filling it with data, it is possible with:

```
nestedVec.size();
```

But if I want to get the size of a nested deque, I am getting 0:

```
nestedVec.vec1.size();
```

There is data in it and I can access it, but I can not get the size. Is there a way to get the size of a nested deque?

Comment: Show how you fill it with data. And don't use `typedef struct`. It's not needed. This is not C

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify which structure inside the deque you want to access.

```
nestedVec[i].vec1.size(); // note the [i]
```

Otherwise there is no way to be able to figure out which structure you want to get and which deque to access.

Comment: I am sorry, i forgot the index here in this post!
I corrected it, but i made it right in my code,  but it does not work either.

Comment: It does, that's how you get the size of your dequeue. Otherwise, it's an issue int he code you are not showing.

Comment: either the edit of the question should be rolled back or this answer is completely pointless, @Firas94 in any case, you should tell us the exact error and show the code that causes the error

Comment: @user463035818 I hope OP will update the question, then I can edit the answer for something more adapted (or indeed, roll it back).